# GROUP BY in SUBQUERY WITH UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, subquery, union-all

I have two tables, one showing the search queries history, the other showing the locations.

The first table is for the search queries: searchTerm | date | userId | historyId
The second is for the locations: userId | date | historyId | lat | lng

I am using UNION ALL to bring these together in a sub query with JOIN LEFT & JOIN RIGHT to create a FULL JOIN.

```
SELECT st, fa FROM
                 (SELECT webHistory.searchTerm AS st, locationHistory.fullAddress AS fa
                  FROM webHistory LEFT OUTER JOIN locationHistory
                  ON webHistory.historyId=locationHistory.historyId
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT webHistory.searchTerm as st, locationHistory.fullAddress AS fa
                  FROM webHistory RIGHT OUTER JOIN locationHistory
                  ON webHistory.historyId=locationHistory.historyId) t
```

Every thing is working beautifully I'm getting results for just entries in webHistory table, and the same for the locationHistory table. The issue I have is when I'm getting rows that have been added to both. They show twice!

I can't just use union as it will JOIN more than I want it to. If two of the same searches are added, instead of showing two it will join them into one. So I need to use UNION ALL.

I have to use union as I'm JOINing from the LEFT and RIGHT and in mySql FULL JOIN isn't supported.

So I'm assuming I need to GROUP BY historyId as this id will always be the same on rows added at the same time (when a search is made by query and location). Problem is, i've tried and tested but I can't seem to get this to work. Am I missing something?

Lastly, while I'm asking a question and because I've not yet got to the point of testing this would the ORDER BY `date` be on the OUTER or SUBQUERIES as I want to show the most recent as the first result?

/* More Information */

I need to to output:

SearchTerm if there is no fullAddress.
Full address if there is no searchTerm.
SearchTerm & fullAddress if there is both.

Currently it outputs the first two fine, but the latter will output twice.

Comment: Could you give some sample data and a desired result? I'm having a hard time understanding exactly the result you'd like to see.

Comment: Sorry I was having a hard time explaining it, I'll add more information now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as understand, you want duplicates with the same historyId to be eliminated, so you should be able to use `UNION` as long as the historyId is included in the `UNION` so that duplicates with *another* historyId won't be eliminated;

```
SELECT st, fa FROM
 (SELECT webHistory.searchTerm AS st, 
         locationHistory.fullAddress AS fa, 
         webHistory.historyId
  FROM webHistory LEFT OUTER JOIN locationHistory
  ON webHistory.historyId=locationHistory.historyId
  UNION
  SELECT webHistory.searchTerm as st, 
         locationHistory.fullAddress AS fa,
         locationHistory.historyId
  FROM webHistory RIGHT OUTER JOIN locationHistory
  ON webHistory.historyId=locationHistory.historyId) t
```